Как реализовать имплементацию JS, если он генерируется автоматически
Задача состоит в том, чтобы внедрить JavaScript в страницу. А беда вся в том, что он в моем случае не статичен и генерируется автоматически. Т.е. минимально-воспроизводимый пример выглядит как-то так:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../?key=sYdQHpBYyXiRyUNZtNcZkP1yAE15u4AQ"></script>

http://.../?key=sYdQHpBYyXiRyUNZtNcZkP1yAE15u4AQ выдает следующий контент...
alert("Hurra!");

...но ничего, почему-то не срабатывает.
Мне приходит в голову динамическая загрузка через AJAX и последующая валидация, но специфика задачи такая, чтобы обойтись минимальным размером кода, желательно одной строчкой...Рад, если предложите элегантное решение.

да как бэ это....... создаешь тег script через createElement, добавляешь в него атрибуты и дальше просто делаешь append в body

@АлексейШиманский, я понимаю. Только вот я разрабатываю сервис, где реализация должна быть желательно максимально простой...т.е. нужно просто подключить js одной строчкой...такое в моем случае возможно?

ну вроде body.append = 'html строка' . вместо append возможно использовать insertAdjacentHTML

Спасибо! Мне кажется, можно реализовать через mod_rewrite, но не хотелось глубоко погружаться в конфигурацию веб-сервера...

Причём тут mod_rewrite ? :DDDD

Чтобы "выдавать" динамически генерируемые странички за статичные файлы .js Если бы в атрибуте src тэга script было бы так, то проблемы никакой не было бы...

Нашел решение! Нужно просто было указать MIME-тип файла при отправке его в ответ на запрос. Т.к. я пишу, используя Django, то в моем случае нужно было заменить это...
return HttpResponse(file_content)

...на это...
return HttpResponse(file_content, content_type='application/javascript')

